# Daypilot how to load data in chunks?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have table Daypilot Sheduler, my problem is that I download very much data and this very long render my table, I think that if download data chunks thats be fine. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asU9w.png) I need do that rooms donwload chunks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please describe what you have tried so far and what problem are you having. Have you considered paging?